# SSLError using pip install tweepy

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, tweepy

After install Anaconda3, I continue to install tweepy package, but I got an SSLError:

> Retrying(Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))after connection broken by 'SSLError("bad handshake": Error([('SSL routine's, 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),)': /simple/tweepy/

[image: SSLError pip install].

I try to install some other packages but I get the same error. I referenced a solution to fix it:
1: conda config --set ssl_verify false
2: conda update requests
3: conda config --set ssl_verify true

After three steps, I try to install again, but it remains old error. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: It would be better if you  pasted the important part of the error message as text so that is become searchable.

Comment: Retrying(Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))after connection broken by 'SSLError("bad handshake": Error([('SSL routine's, 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')]

Comment: This is my message of error that I got. Can you help me to fix it?

Comment: @KimThoa Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I find the problem and fix it. This problem is turn on the proxy server in LAN setting. So, I turn off it and I can pip install any package. Thank you all.